# Separate space-delimited words in a string

Tags: php, string

I have a text string in the following format

```
$str= "word1 word2 word3 word4 ";
```

So I want to separate each word from the string. Two words are separated by a blank space
How do I do that? Is there any built-in function to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest would be to use [`explode`](http://docs.php.net/explode):

```
$words = explode(' ', $str);
```

But that does only accept fixed separators. [`split`](http://docs.php.net/split) an [`preg_split`](http://docs.php.net/preg_split) do accept regular expressions so that your words can be separated by multiple spaces:

```
$words = split('\s+', $str);
// or
$words = preg_split('/\s+/', $str);
```

Now you can additionally remove leading and trailing spaces with [`trim`](http://docs.php.net/trim):

```
$words = preg_split('/\s+/', trim($str));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$words = explode( ' ', $str );
```

See: http://www.php.net/explode

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/explode

edit: damn, Rob was faster

Answer (score 0):

Pay careful attention to the fact that the OP's sample input has a trailing space on all words.  So, not only are the words separated by spaces, there is also a trailing space.

To overcome this with a single, non-regex function call, use `str_word_count()` with a character mask to allow the inclusion of numbers as part of valud words.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/dOP7H))

```
$str = "word1 word2 word3 word4 ";

var_export(str_word_count($str, 1, '0..9'));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'word1',
  1 => 'word2',
  2 => 'word3',
  3 => 'word4',
)
```