# split sentence with variable number of words (separated by blank spaces) into words and then build sentence with & as delimiter

Tags: php

For instance, in one case the sentence can have 2 words, and in other case the sentence can have 5 words. I think that I can use explode to get every word in each case (something like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481141/separate-space-delimited-words-in-a-string)), the problem is that the number of words in each sentence varies. After that initial problem, I need to resemble the sentence but using & instead of blank spaces, e.g.,

```
input:   this is a sentence
output:  this & is & a & sentence
```

I'm new in php, so please bear with me if this question is very simple.

Thanks in advance for any hints!

Comment: `$result = implode(' & ', str_word_count($original,2));`

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks for that nice line command. One question about it, I know that in awk I can use `awk '{ if ( x < 2) print $0 }' file` to use a simple if call. Is it possible to do something similar in your command? the thing is that I want to leave the sentence if it has only one word, and apply your line command if it has 2 or more words, thanks for any further suggestions.

Comment: Not testing for the word count as part of a clean one-liner; but if you only have one word in the sentence, then you'll only have one word in the end result without any ampersand

Comment: @MarkBaker just tested it and you're right, it gives the same input, cool answer, thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) -

```
$sentence = "this is a sentence";
$words = explode(' ', $sentence);
print_r($words);
```

And then [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) -

```
$updated = implode(" & ", $words);
echo $updated;
```

This method does not care how many words are in the sentence, so it can be used with any sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split the words by space. Then use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to put them back together with the & between the words.

```
$string = 'this is a sentence';
$words = explode(' ', $string);
$newstring = implode(' & ', $words);
var_dump($newstring);
```

Or you can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace all spaces with the &.

```
$string = 'this is a sentence';
$newstring = str_replace(' ', ' & ', $string);
```